# How to detect which application is clicked/launched by the user through my application in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to know whether there is any receiver to detect which application is clicked or launched/started by user via my own application

Answer (score 0):

this is deprecated as of android 4.1 an app has access only to its own logs with android.permission.READ_LOGS